# How to get python Script output in Text file ,without overwriting current one text file

Tags: python, batch-file

Hello I have written python code which run by task scheduler. This code delete the folder which are older than 5 days. code is working fine but I took output of this code in log text file. whenever code run existing log file overwritten. I want see every schedule log , that's not possible now.
How I can get output of code in different file every time or in same file without overwriting data.

```
import os
import sys
import datetime
import shutil
path=r"C:\Users\Iliyas\OneDrive\Documents"
all_dir=os.listdir(path)
age=5
today=datetime.datetime.now()
for each_dir in all_dir:
    each_dir_path=os.path.join(path,each_dir)
    if os.path.isdir(each_dir_path):
       die_cre_date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(each_dir_path))
       dif_days=(today-die_cre_date).days
       if dif_days > age:
           print(f' The {each_dir_path} folder in older the {dif_days} days, deleting it:')
           shutil.rmtree(each_dir_path)
           print("path deleted")
       else:
           print("there is nothing delete older than 5 days")
           break
```

This code run by .bat file in task scheduler

```
D:\Python\python.exe D:\Code\Delete_Files_older_than_5_days.py > D:\code\Log\Delete_data_log.txt
```

Comment: Redirect, `>` writes `stdout` to a file or `nul`. it will always create the file if it does not exist and always re-write the file if exist. To append to a file `>>` is used. It will also create the file if it does not exist, but will not overwrite the file and will append to the file if it exists. To redirect `stderr` instead (where supported) use `2>>` or to redirect the `stdout` stream to `stdout` where both be appended to the file use `2>&1` with the redirect. Lastly it is also possible to split `stderr` and `stdout` as `>output.log 2>error.log` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `>>` to append `stdout` to a file.

```
D:\Python\python.exe D:\Code\Delete_Files_older_than_5_days.py >> D:\code\Log\Delete_data_log.txt
```

Comment: That's resolve my issue